Expected value of derivative derivative squared log equivalent to regularity condition
I'm given the following information (*):
$\mathbb E[(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} log f(X_1, ..., X_n; \theta))^2] = - \mathbb E[(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 \theta} log f(X_1, ..., X_n; \theta))$
Now, let $f(x; \theta)$ be a regular parametric model (not necess. an exponential family) such that X = {$ x \in \mathbb R : f(x; \theta) > 0 $}
does not depend on $\theta$ and $f$ twice differentiable with respect to $\theta$. Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be iid $f(x; \theta)$.
How is to show that the equality (*) is equivalent to a regularity condition allowing us to interchange integration and differentiation?
Thanks for any help.

The very relation depends on the fact that interchanging the differentiation under the integral sign is valid.
Consider a random variable $\mathbf X$ takes values on the space $(\mathscr X,\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}_\mathscr X)$ with the distribution function absolutely continuous with respect to a $\sigma$–finite measure $\mu$ -- this means it has a density $f_\theta(\mathbf x) , $ where $\theta$ is the (unknown) index parameter (to be estimated).
\begin{align}0 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\int_\mathscr X f_\theta(\mathbf x) ~\mathrm d\mu(\mathbf x) \\ &\color{red}{=}\int_\mathscr X \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f_\theta(\mathbf x) ~\mathrm d\mu(\mathbf x)\\&=\int_\mathscr X \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln f_\theta(\mathbf x)\cdot f_\theta(\mathbf x) ~\mathrm d\mu(\mathbf x) \\\implies 0&=\int_\mathscr X\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln f_\theta(\mathbf x)\cdot f_\theta(\mathbf x) \right]~\mathrm d\mu(\mathbf x)\\ 0&= \int_\mathscr X\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\ln f_\theta(\mathbf x)\cdot f_\theta(\mathbf x) ~\mathrm d\mu(\mathbf x)+  \int_\mathscr X\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \ln f_\theta(\mathbf x)\right\}^2 f_\theta(\mathbf x) ~\mathrm d\mu(\mathbf x)\\ &= \mathbb E_\theta\left\{\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\ln f_\theta(\mathbf X) \right\}+ \mathbb E_\theta\left\{\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln f_\theta(\mathbf X) \right)^2\right\}.\end{align}
Notice above where we interchanged $\partial_\theta$ with the integral.
